# How to add incrementing number to end of each uploaded file using PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, auto-increment

I have a script that uploads each file in a specific directory to my WordPress site. Right now, the script only uploads one image, the last image in the directory. I believe my problem is in the for loop that is assigning the uploaded files name. Here is my code:

```
   function vehicle_image_uploads() {
?>
    <button id="veh_img_upload">Upload Images</button>

<?php
    global $post;

    $rpcurl = get_bloginfo('url') . "/xmlrpc.php";

    echo $rpcurl; 

    $username = 'admin';
    $password = 'admin';
    $blogid = $post->ID; //Post ID

    echo $blogid;

    $post_idn = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'VIN', true);

    echo "<h1>" . $post_idn ."</h1>";

    $post_dir = dirname( get_template_directory() ) . "/" . $post_idn;

    $fileslist = scandir($post_dir);

    foreach ($fileslist as $file) {
        echo $file;
    }

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($fileslist as $file) {

        if( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) {
            continue;
        }

        $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

        $filetype = "image/jpeg";

        $filename = "remote_filename_". $i .".jpg";
         $i++; //


        xmlrpc_set_type($file,'base64'); // <-- required!
        $params = array($blogid,$username,$password,
                    array('name'=>$filename,'type'=>$filetype,'bits'=>$file,'overwrite'=>false));
        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);

        echo "<br />" . $filename;

    }



    function go($request,$rpcurl){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$rpcurl);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    $result = go($request,$rpcurl);
    print_r($result);


}
```

What I am wanting to do is name each upload file "remote_filename" with _1, _2, _3 etc. etc. added to the end of each file.

Comment: What is the point of that loop at all? All it will do is eventually end up with `$filename = "remote_filename_". $basenumber.".jpg";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to using external iterator, and also:

Where is the actual RPC taking place?
Can you extend your code snippet to show that?

Maybe you call it just once already oustide of the `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach ($fileslist as $file) {
    //...
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.uploadFile',$params);
}
$file = file_get_contents($rpcurl, ...); //or however you call it
```

It would produce the effect, you're experiencing - no matter what uploading only one file (the last one you processed from the list).

It should be called inside the loop, for every file.

Comment: For some reason, I didn't add the full code sorry about that. I have updated the OP with the whole thing.

Comment: Your code shows exactly the problem I was talking about. You only call `go` once - at the end of the script. Move it up, inside the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a loop going on `$filelist`; add a counter before and use that to increment:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($fileslist as $file) {

    if( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) {
        continue;
    }

    $file = file_get_contents( $post_dir . "/" . $file);

    $filetype = "image/jpeg";

    $filename = "remote_filename_". $i .".jpg";
    $i++; //increment $i
```

Comment: It's still just uploading one file.

Comment: Try doing `print_r($fileslist)` to actually see how many files are getting picked up?

Comment: It's picking up all three images. There are only three files in the directory right now. So when I run a foreach statement echoing each file in $fileslist I get the name of each file in the directory. If I echo the $filename variable it lists out each file with the associated number on the end.

Comment: I think something else is going wrong then -- if $filename is correct at the point of entry into your xmlrpc_set_type function, something may be wrong on that end? can you `print_r($params)` before you call the request?

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense with the added function.